# 次の2つのprotocolの書き方は同じことを表現できていますか？　それとも違う意味ですか？

Tags: swift

次の2つのプロトコルの書き方は同じことを表現できていますか？　それとも違う意味ですか？

ソース1

```
protocol Hogeable: AnyObject {}
extension Hogeable where Self: UIViewController {}
```

と

ソース2

```
protocol Hogeable: UIViewController {}
extension Hogeable {}
```

ソース1の書き方をよく見るような気がしたのですが、どこかのSwfitのバージョンでソース2の書き方もできるようになったりしましたでしょうか？

上記のコードは空っぽですが、
`Hogeable`の`extension`内は`UIViewController`であることが前提のソースコードを書かれていることを想定しています（`navigationController`にアクセスするとか)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自分自身ソース2みたいな書き方ができたっけ?とか思ってしまったのですが、こちらですね。

[Swift 5 Release Notes for Xcode 10.2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2)

[Resolved Issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2#3136868)

> - Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:
>
> ```
> protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ }
> protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> Swift 4.2 accepted the second form, but it wasn’t fully implemented
>   and could sometimes crash at compile time or runtime. (SR-5581) (38077232)

Swift 4.2までは、上記2つ目の書き方は「エラーは出ないけどまともに動かなかった」と言うことだったのですが、Swift 5でそのバグが修正された際に、上記1個目と2個目の書き方は等価、と明確化されたようです。(実際には他のバージョンでも「エラーは出ない」ものはあるかも知れません。【追記】Xcode 9.4.1でも10.1でもダメだったんで、Swift 5より以前は構文的にエラーになっていたと思われます。)

と言うわけで、ご質問内の「ソース2」の書き方は、

```
protocol Hogeable where Self: UIViewController {}
extension Hogeable {}
```

と等価と言うことになります。

ちなみに「ソース1」の書き方はSwift 4で、[Class and Subtype existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md)が導入された折に旧来の`:class`と等価であると定められました。ですから、こちらと等価。

```
protocol Hogeable: class {}
extension Hogeable where Self: UIViewController {}
```

---

従って、
***次の2つのプロトコルの書き方は同じことを表現できていますか？　それとも違う意味ですか？***
の答えは、

**違う意味です。**

と言うことになります。「ソース1」の方では、プロトコル`Hogeable`には、任意のクラスが適合することが出来ますが、「ソース2」の方は、`UIViewController`のサブクラスしか`Hogeable`に適合することが出来ません。

「ソース1」型の宣言

```
protocol Hogeable: AnyObject {}
extension Hogeable where Self: UIViewController {
    var testProperty: String {
        return "test"
    }
}

class MyClass: Hogeable {} //<- ここではエラーが出ない
let myObj = MyClass()
print(myObj.testProperty) //<- ここでエラーになる
```

「ソース2」型の場合

```
protocol Hogeable: UIViewController {}
extension Hogeable {
    var testProperty: String {
        return "test"
    }
}

class MyClass: Hogeable {} //<- ここで既にエラー
let myObj = MyClass()
print(myObj.testProperty) //<- 当然ここもエラーだが、上のエラーのせいで無視されるかも
```